# react-testing-library: userEvent.click throws error when ThemeProvider wrapped Component in render

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have a Search.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    divStyle: {
        width: theme.spacing(2)
    }
}))


function Search() {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
    const classes = styles();

    return (
        <div className={classes.divStyle}>
        <FormControl>
            <InputLabel  id="country">Country</InputLabel>
            <Select
            data-testid="country"
            labelId="country"
            onChange={({ target: { value } }) => setCountry(value)}
            value={country}
            style={{ minWidth: 120 }}
            >
            <MenuItem value="brazil">Brazil</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="japan">Japan</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="usa">United States</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    </div>
    )
   
}

export default Search
```

and a Search.test.js

```
import Search from "../Search";

import { render, waitFor, screen ,getByRole} from '@testing-library/react';
import { createTheme } from "@mui/system";

import UserEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";

describe('Search', () => {
    const mainTheme = createTheme({
        spacing: 4,
    });

    it('test1', async () => {
        render(
              <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
                    <SearchForm />
                </ThemeProvider>
        )
        UserEvent.click(getByRole(screen.getByTestId("country"), "button"));
      
        //the following test cannot be run
        ...
    })
})
```

when I run my test the error shows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'duration' of undefined                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      71 |                 </ThemeProvider>                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      72 |         )                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    > 73 |         UserEvent.click(getByRole(screen.getByTestId("country"), "button"));
         |                   ^
      74 |         // let button = screen.getByRole("button");
      75 |         // console.log('button',button)
      76 |         // UserEvent.click(button);

      at Fade (node_modules/@mui/material/node/Fade/Fade.js:52:30)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
      at updateForwardRef (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19226:20)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21636:16)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26560:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
      at recoverFromConcurrentError (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26096:20)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:12042:22)
      at flushActQueue (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2667:24)
      at act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2582:11)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:63:25
      at Object.eventWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:78:28)
      at fireEvent (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:16:35)
      at Function.fireEvent.<computed> [as mouseDown] (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/events.js:125:36)
      at clickElement (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:73:52)
      at Object.click (node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/click.js:140:5)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/Search.test.js:73:19)
```

It works fines when I remove everything about theme/style in Search.jsx and Search.test.js
I did a lot of research but still cannot find the reason of this
Does anyone know what happens after I add a ThemeProvider ?

- screens.debug() can print the DOM no matter the ThemeProvider  exist or not

Comment: problem solved. The reason is due to import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/styles";

Comment: import ThemeProvider from '@mui/material/styles' can fix the problem